# Changing the value of one Object affects other

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am facing a strange problem.

I have a class:

```
public class HeatMap {
    public View view;
    public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams orignalParam;
    public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams centerParam;
    public int originalPos[]=new int[2];
    public boolean Position;
    public float Positions[]=new float[2];
    public int centerPos[]=new int[2];
    public HeatMap(View view){
        this.view=view;
        this.Position=false;
        orignalParam= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        centerParam =
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

    }
```

and in another class I am doing the following things

```
    static HeatMap staticView;

  public static void TranslateViewAtCenter1(Context context, int pop){

        HeatMap hMap=Constants.heatMapList.get(pop);



 staticView=hMap;

      //  staticView.centerParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
       // staticView.view.setLayoutParams(hMap.centerParam);
        View rootChild = hMap.view;
        int originalPos[] = new int[2];
        rootChild.getLocationOnScreen(originalPos);

        int mainViewWidth=HomeScreenActivity.rl_heatmap_view.getMeasuredWidth();
        int mainViewHeight=HomeScreenActivity.rl_heatmap_view.getMeasuredHeight();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp= (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)rootChild.getLayoutParams();

        int left=lp.leftMargin;
        int top=lp.topMargin;


        Log.e("ORGPOs_center", hMap.originalPos[0] + " , " + hMap.originalPos[1] + " ," + hMap.view.getId());
        Log.e("XXWidhtHeight",rootChild.getMeasuredWidth()+" , "+rootChild.getMeasuredHeight());


        int xDest = mainViewWidth/2;
        xDest -= (rootChild.getMeasuredWidth()/2);
        int yDest = mainViewHeight/2 - (rootChild.getMeasuredHeight()/2)/*-statusBarOffset*/;
        int xD= CommonMethods.pxToDp(xDest-left,context);
        int yD= CommonMethods.pxToDp(yDest - top, context);
        hMap.centerPos[0]=xD;
        hMap.centerPos[1]=yD;


        TranslateIntoCenter intoCenter=new TranslateIntoCenter();
        intoCenter.setView(hMap);


        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( xD, 0 , yD, 0 );
        anim.setAnimationListener(intoCenter);
        anim.setDuration(500);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        hMap.view.startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

The problem is in these two lines

```
staticView.centerParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
       staticView.view.setLayoutParams(hMap.centerParam);
```

If I comment these lines every thing works perfect for `hMap` but on changing `staticView` properties the `hMap` also changed. I have checked the whole code I am not using `staticView` or doing any thing with `staticView` any where else.

Thanks.

Comment: You got a reference here `staticView=hMap`

Comment: Yeah I am assiging 'hMap' to 'staticView' and than changing the 'staticView' this should not affect 'hMap' but it is changing 'hMap'

Comment: I'm not going to read all that code (so that might not be your problem), just note that in your first code block, `orignalParam` and `centerParam` refer to the same object. So if you change something inside `centerParam`, `originalParam` will have the change too

Comment: And it's the same problem with ` staticView=hMap;` staticView is the reference to hMap. So if you change staticView, hMap will be changed too. You need to create a copy of the object if you want two different views

Comment: Okay if I create a new object 'staticView=new HeatMap(hMap.view);' it is also behaving the same.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno just need a new object with all the values of 'hMap'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding the line

```
staticView=hMap;
```

You are obtaining a reference to the hMap object. You are not creating a new object. Which means staticView and hMap both point to the same object and if you make changes in any one of them, they would be reflected in both staticView and hMap.

You have to create a new object of HeatMap

Comment: Okay if I create a new object 'staticView=new HeatMap(hMap.view);' it is also behaving the same.  Am I creating new object right?

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out the issue can you please help in the solution too? I just need a new object with all the values of 'hMap'.

Comment: I don't have just calling them straight.

Comment: Try removing the static from HeatMap